# Yarn memory allocation for spark streaming

Tags: hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

When we use spark on yarn for non-streaming apps, we generally get the allocated memory to match the number of executors times memory per executor. When doing streaming apps, the allocated memory is immediately pushed to the limit (total memory) as shown in the yarn console.

With this set of parameters
--driver-memory 2g --num-executors 32 --executor-memory 500m
total memory 90G, memory used 85.88G
total vcores 64, vcores used 33

you would expect a basis of 32 * 1 G (500m + overhead) + driver memory or around 34 G, and 33 vcores (32 workers + 1 driver)

question:

1. is the 64 vcore due to the requirement of 2 core pairs for streaming connection and processing?
2. how did the estimated 34 G get pushed to 85.88 G? is this always true that with streaming apps, yarn gives it all it has?

Comment: What dstream do you use? Ad 1. is only applied when you use input dstreams with receivers (that may or may not be your case).

Comment: Its ReceiverInputStream. Your statement is a little too concise for me. Please elaborate what is Ad. 1.